# Sql server database synchronisation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, synchronization, data-synchronization

I have 1 application , in which conditions are like i have to use local databases only for each PC....Now if some enrollment is done from 1 pc then that data should be store in local database and also it should be send to another PC...in short i want to synchronise all the data..

I need to clear 1 thing that "Centralize database is not possible..I cant use 1 database and connect to it from all PC.."So i need synchronization only...

I am using SQL SERVER Express Edition...
and developing application in C# .NET

If have any doubt you can ask me i will describe more...

[image: Databse Synchronisation]

Comment: So why wouldn't querying both databases at the same time work (not the best solution, but if there are only two databases, and there isn't a huge load)?  I'm guessing you have thought of this, but I don't see the issue with it (yet).

Comment: there are almost 130 PC(database)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server Express, replication is not an option. (Express versions can only subscribe in a replication scenario.) But you should take a look at the [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002.aspx), formerly known as Sync Services for ADO.NET. It is an API for .NET that provides the kind of db sync capabilities which you may find helpful. From your description, the [Collaboration Scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902853.aspx) seems the most applicable (peer-to-peer synchronization scenario.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, if you really want data redundancy, looking at something like [cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) might be a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks...but i am looking some solution for c# .net....i am not a java person..so cant understand the java code ...